# Audio Payload Dialogflow (api.ai)

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, api-ai

I'm making an action for the Google Assistant. I do have a javascript fullfilment but it's not really a good clear code it works so it's fine. By example, I don't know how to call an intent in js. But on to my question: is it possible to use the custom payload response for audio files? ***I know you can play audio files with the webhook but it would be lovely if it just possible in de custom payload.***

I want my welcome intent to have an audio response. If it's not possible how do I call the welcome intent in js?

My webhook now: [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what you mean by the "custom payload" and exactly how long the audio you want to play is, but there are a number of ways you can play audio that you have configured from the Dialogflow settings. You can also play it from PHP using similar methods in some cases.

**Playing short audio**

Your speech responses can include [SSML markup](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml) which can include an `<audio>` tag that includes audio. This audio *must be under 120 seconds long*. So you can have something like this:

```
<speak>Welcome to my action! <audio src="https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/alarms/bugle_tune.ogg"></audio> How can I help you?</speak>
```

either in the Response Default tab or if you add a Simple Response in the Google Assistant tab. In the Default tab, it looks something like this:

[image]

If you're making a response for the Google Assistant only, you can do it in that tab by clicking on the "Google Assistant" tab and then "Add Responses"

[image]

You can then select a "Simple Response" to add and enter the SSML.

[image]

[image]

**Playing longer audio**

If your audio is longer than 120 seconds, you can add a *Media Response* to the Google Assistant response. You need to have a Simple Response already set and then click "Add Responses" to add another.

[image]

You may need to scroll down to select "Media Content".

[image]

Then add the information for the content. You need to provide, at a minimum, a name that will be displayed on screen-based devices and the URL for the audio.

[image]